# YouCompleteMe and CUDA source files

Tags: vim, plugins

I am trying to make YCM plugin of vim to work for CUDA source files.
Since CUDA is basically C++ syntax with some extensions, I thought that editing the standard '.ycm_extra_conf.py' file would be sufficient. I changed the line

```
SOURCE_EXTENSIONS = [ '.cpp', '.cxx', '.cc', '.c', '.m', '.mm']
```

to

```
SOURCE_EXTENSIONS = [ '.cpp', '.cxx', '.cc', '.c', '.m', '.mm', '.cu' ]
```

and the line

```
return extension in [ '.h', '.hxx', '.hpp', '.hh']
```

to

```
return extension in [ '.h', '.hxx', '.hpp', '.hh', '.cuh' ]
```

But YCM does not work, it does not even ask me to use the config file as it should in the beginning. In normal C/C++ source files YCM works correct.

Any ideas what is missing?

Comment: You probably need to whitelist it in `g:ycm_filetype_whitelist` or some other vim script variable.

Comment: I took your advice and used the whitelist option, using both general * and 'cuda' keywords, but no luck. I had hope that option would be the solution.

Comment: since CUDA uses the 'nvcc' compiler, I start to believe maybe it is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

I got this working by the following steps:

First remap .cu files to cpp in your .vimrc

```
" Map cuda files to c++ so that Ycm can parse
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.cu set filetype=cpp
```

Next update .ycm_extra_conf.py with flags for Clang CUDA support.

```
import os
import ycm_core

includes = ['-I/opt/cudatoolkit/6.5/include', '-I/your/includes/here']

common = ['-std=c++11',
          '-DUSE_CLANG_COMPLETER',
          '-I/usr/local/include',
          '-I/usr/include/clang/3.5/include',
          '-I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu',
          '-I/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include',
          '-I/usr/include',
          '-I/usr/include/c++/4.9']

cpp_flags = ['-x', 'c++',]

# http://llvm.org/docs/CompileCudaWithLLVM.html
cuda_flags = ['-x', 'cuda', '--cuda-gpu-arch=sm_35']

def FlagsForFile( filename ):

  compile_flags = cpp_flags
  if filename.endswith('.cu'):
    compile_flags = cuda_flags
  compile_flags.extend(common)
  compile_flags.extend(includes)

  return {
    'flags': compile_flags,
    'do_cache': True
  }
```

Finally you need to add in a header file to your .cu file so Ycm can parse the CUDA builtins. This file, `cuda_builtin_vars.h` was in my local Clang build.

```
#ifdef __clang__
#include <cuda_builtin_vars.h>
#endif
```

Even with all this, the Clang parser still doesn't seem to accept that my `__global__` functions are actually `__global__` (even though it can handle the kernel call syntax with any problems), so I usually wrap them with  `#ifndef __clang__`

Sources:

- https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/1766
- http://llvm.org/docs/CompileCudaWithLLVM.html
- https://github.com/Microsoft/clang-1/blob/master/test/SemaCUDA/kernel-call.cu